# Consider the ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$, where $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$, where $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as follow

$$ f(x,y) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}  & (x,y)\neq(0,0), \\
  0 & (x,y)=(0,0)
 \end{array}
\right.$$

a) Show that the given ODE admits solutions for arbitrary initial conditions $y(x_0)=x_0$

b) ¿Does $f$ locally satisfiy the conditions for Picard's Theorem?,

c) ¿And what about Peano's existence theorem? Justify

My attemps:

To solve the ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ for $(x_0,y_0)\neq(0,0)$ I tried it by separable variable method and the solution was

$$ \ln(y)=\frac{x^2}{2y^2}+C$$

How do I conclude a),b) and c).

Can somebody give me a hint?